# need to know the behaviour of titanfactory open method

Tags: titan

I am working on POC of titan DB and following the GraphOfTheGods example .
  TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open(args[0]);

can any one please guide me when concurrent users will try to open the same instance of Titangraph ,whether everyone will get the same instance or different instance .

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get a different instance of the graph everytime you load it in. This means different users can affect the graph simultaneously. I would recommend reading into [Transactions](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/tx.html) if you going to have multiple users accessing and writing into the graph simultaneously. Be aware that Titan can autocommit changes as you do them. So your users may accidentally affect each other if this is not handled correctly.

Personally I use this:

```
titanGraph.tx().onClose(Transaction.CLOSE_BEHAVIOR.ROLLBACK);
```

to have more explicit control over when changes are committed.